# Getting Garbled Alert popup in Yosemite

Tags: macos, dmg

When I clicked on a proprietary dmg, I found this garbled alert. Whereas previously in the 10.8.x version, this DMG message is clear, it is unreadable with 10.9 and later.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Wow, that dialog hit every branch on the ugly tree as it tumbled to the ground. What version and build of OS X is running? Can you share the link to the file so that others might check if the problem is the DMG?

Comment: OSX version is 10.10.2. It is fine in  till 10.9.x OSX versions. We are seeing this only from 10.10.x and further.DMG is confidential and moreover issue is with this popup

Comment: I've added the details to the text of the question. What now? Do you want to learn how to repackage the DMG or sign the package with gatekeeper so that you don't get warnings or run disk utility to understand the problems? What info or goal is the end point. Please use the edit to clarify what you seek and then I can purge all the comments...

Comment: Actually i have done lot of research and left out this alert popup.  As i am creating DMG file in centos and keeping in portal. From where we download it. I signed my pkg file using pkgbuild and signed it. DMG is created at the time of download with some system specific files .  So i cannot stop this alert message. But my current problem is  that this pop is garbled and ugly when we download from yesomite.

Comment: I can move this to Stack Overflow if you think this is a code level problem. Perhaps someone will have seen this here, but if you're crafting the image - you'll need to explain in detail how that happens and we tend to focus on user problems and not developer problems.

Comment: I've seen this dialog on a DMG I opened too. I don't remember what it was, but it was software I had downloaded. It's a system problem. I don't believe it has anything to do with your dmg.